# Gemara with Rashi in "regular" script

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, jewish-books, rashi, text

I am overseeing the creation of a beis medrash program for high schoolers with zero exposure to traditional texts, and am looking for editions of the gemara--with the standard vilna layout--but have the Rashi in regular script. Vowels are not needed, just the regular script.

This question has not already been answered (as far as I can see), as other questions asked about online sources. I am looking for physical books for the students to buy.

TIA!

Comment: Although it's lacking the layout, but you can try the text version of the shas on HebrewBooks, alternatively, you can create source sheets on Sefaria. I'm not aware of an edition that you described. I thought about the Steinsaltz edition, but even there the Rashi is in "Rashi" script.

Comment: I’m not sure that such a product exists, as I doubt there is much of a market for it. Traditionally, kids who are being exposed to Talmud for the first time shouldn’t have much problem with “Rashi” script, having previously learned Chumash with Rashi’s commentary (as well as possibly commentaries on mishnah printed in this script).

Comment: I thought the best chance of finding this would be Tuvia's Gemara Menukad, but there too (based on what I could see online) it's still in Rashi script, just with vowels.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It looks like this, in fact, does not exist! Guess it is time to buckle down and team them Rashi Script.
@Dov that doesn't answer the question as it is looking for online sources, and I am looking for printed versions.